# What does k stand for in gitk?

Tags: git

I wonder k must mean something in gitk. Could not find it on Google.

Found that git was named by Linus Torvalds out of imagination. But when a tool was added with name gitk, there must be something in their mind.

https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Git-called-Git

Comment: **Pro tip:** If you're not sure you're in the right "forum," you probably aren't.

Comment: Thanks Robert, do you have any suggestion about which forum I should have posted this question in. Will use it in future.

Comment: @SBirthare a better approach would have been to search a bit first. For example, [reading about it](http://wiki.tcl.tk/14598) (or the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gitk)) and then drawing some conclusions about wording from the History section of the documentation (or second paragraph of the man page) such as "Gitk was the first graphical repository browser. It’s written in tcl/tk and started off in a separate repository but was later merged into the main Git repository."

Comment: Thanks Michael, I did tried to search. And that's the approach I usually take. But in this case i hardly find a little about git. So assumed its mystery and  asked here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Gitk is built on top of a GUI library named "Tk", a graphical **t**ool**k**it originally designed for the Tcl language.  "Gitk" is a combination of "Git" + "Tk" and then they removed the extra "t" in the middle. Thus, "k" literally stands for "kit".

Comment: Sure, I was just curious to know if k stand for something. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: So they picked up 'k' from 'toolKit' and added it to 'git' to make it 'gitk'.

Comment: Like I said, it's because gitk is a GUI for git built using tk.